# Fabric js custom rotate icon not showing on initial load

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have the following code for changing the rotate icon in fabric js:
http://jsfiddle.net/2XZHp/194/

```
//Replace rotate icon
isVML = function() { return typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== 'undefined'; };

// overriding _drawControl method
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    selectedIconImage: new Image(),
    iconSrc: 'http://www.navifun.net/files/pins/tiny/Arrow-Rotate-Clockwise.png',
    isLoaded: false,
    _drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
        if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
            return;
        }
        var size = this.cornerSize;
        isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
        if(control !== 'mtr')   ctx['fillRect'](left, top, size, size);
           if(control === 'mtr') {
            if (this.isLoaded) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.selectedIconImage, left, top, size, size);
            } else {
                var self = this;
                this.selectedIconImage.onload = function() {
                    self.isLoaded = true;
                    ctx.drawImage(self.selectedIconImage, left, top, size, size);
                }
                this.selectedIconImage.src = this.iconSrc;
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

But the rotate icon is not showing on first selection. Only when I start to move the object, or deselect it and select it again.

I have looked at other solutions for changing the icon, but this one seems by far the most elegant. But maybe it is too simple/limited?

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend you to use a base64 string of your image as this would delete the initial waiting time that may be needed to load the image from a remote url: http://jsfiddle.net/2XZHp/197/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that fits your needs, but adding a simple `self.canvas.renderAll()` did the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/2XZHp/195/

```
if (control === "mtr") {
    if (self.isLoaded) {
        ctx.drawImage(self.selectedIconImage, left, top, size, size);
        console.warn("reusing");
    }
    else {
        self.selectedIconImage.onload = function() {
            self.isLoaded = true;
            ctx.drawImage(this, left, top, size, size);
            self.canvas.renderAll();
            console.warn("initial load");
        }
        self.selectedIconImage.src = self.iconSrc;
    } 
}
else {
    ctx.fillRect(left, top, size, size);
}
```

---

It should also work with `self.render(ctx)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2XZHp/196/